# Open specific ViewController when open app from push notification IOS

Tags: ios, parsing, uinavigationcontroller, push, tabbarcontroller

I need to open a specific view controller from a push notification;
This is my mainStoriboard:

[MyStoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDDuZ.png)

I was able to arrived in a ViewController but when i'm there i can't see the tabbar and the navigation controller.
here the code:

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
if (launchOptions != nil)
{
        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                      bundle:nil];
        UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Table1"];

        self.window.rootViewController = vc;

}
return YES;

}
```

Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to "NAVIGATE" to the specific ViewController upon clicking on notification. If that's right then You need to make your way from the root navigation controller to the destination view controller, for that you may want to push that final view controller on the current navigation stack of the application after checking if it's already on the stack or not, and if it's already there you just need to update it, otherwise push that ViewController.

Currently your code just seems to make the final view controller the root view controller, that's why you are not seeing your navigation bar/tab bar.

If you need assistance with code please let me know I'll update my answer.
Good Luck

Comment: That's right,you really understood want i meant.Can you please attach the code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean - another tab should be selected, you can use something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (launchOptions)
    {
        UITabBarController* controller = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
        {
            [controller setSelectedIndex:1]; // Here you should specify correct tab's number
        }

    }

    return YES;
}
```

Otherwise - could you describe your problem more?

Comment: what i'm trying to do is try to arrived on detailview of the table2 when I open the app trough a push notification. with my code that I've used i can arrive in it, but I've lost the navigation controller and the tabbar. I've tried your code but it doesn't work ! - do you need to know more ??

Answer (score 0):

In App delegate you can put this under didReceiveLocalNotification or didRecieveRemoteNotification methods if your tab bar is the initial view controller or traverse accordingly to the tab bar controller.

```
MenuTabBarViewController *controller = (MenuTabBarViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

controller.selectedViewController = [controller.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]; // The tab you want to show.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the launch option keys `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey` and `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` in the launchOptions-Dictionary

Then get detail from notification userinfo,and get currentViewController with rootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = ...//init viewController in storyboard or coed;
    UILocalNotification *notification = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (notification){
        // do something with notification userinfo
        UIViewController *rootController = self.window.rootViewController;
        UIViewController *currentController = rootController;

        if ([currentController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
            currentController = [(UITabBarController *)currentController selectedViewController];
        }

        if ([currentController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
            [(UINavigationController *)currentController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
        }else if ([currentController isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]){
            [currentController.navigationController pushViewController:newVC animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

if your app just in the background, use `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` or `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` instead.

Comment: I use your code in my project,but don't work.The app is open to the usual view.To declare the controller goes well this code?                      UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"bundle:nil];
UIViewController* newVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InviaRicette"];

Comment: Had you init `self.window.rootViewController` first?

Comment: Yes i did.I've added TabBarController.Is that correct?